# Why doesn't the REF function in SQL return a reference, but an object instance in Oracle sql developer?

Tags: reference, oracle-sqldeveloper

REF and VALUE are two reference related functions in SQL. According to the definition on Oracle Database Application Developer’s Guide - Object-Relational Features

- "The REF function in a SQL statement takes as an argument a correlation name (or table
  alias) for an object table or view and returns a reference (a REF) to an object instance from that table or view"
- "the VALUE function takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) for an object table or object view and returns object instances corresponding to rows of the table or view"

Unfortunately, under Oracle SQL Developer, the REF function returned an object instance, rather than a reference.

The testing examples I used are from

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/REF.html#GUID-B7622138-6EB6-4203-B5E7-91CAD52E9DB1

However, when I ran the same statements under SQL Plus, it returned a reference, as expected.

Does anyone know why this happens under Oracle SQL Developer?

Thanks in advance.

Richard

The testing examples I used are from

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/REF.html#GUID-B7622138-6EB6-4203-B5E7-91CAD52E9DB1

```sql
drop type cust_address force;
create type cust_address as object
(STREET                    VARCHAR2(40),
POSTAL_CODE                VARCHAR2(10),
CITY                       VARCHAR2(30),
COUNTRY                    VARCHAR2(20)
)

 CREATE TABLE addresses OF cust_address_typ;

INSERT INTO addresses VALUES (
   '123 First Street', '4GF H1J', 'Our Town', 'Ourcountry');

SELECT REF(e) FROM addresses e;
```

Under Oracle SQL Developer, the REF function returned an object instance, rather than a reference, the same as the use of VALUE function.

```
SYSTEM.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP('123 First Street', '4GF H1J', 'Our Town', 'Ourcountry')
```

Under SQL Plus, the same REF statement returned a reference, as expected.

Comment: Interesting that running as a script does show the reference in the Script Output window, at least in version 22.2 - although missing leading zeros you might see in SQL\*Plus. I don't see an option to stop it showing the object in the Query Result grid though. I don't know how useful the ref would be there though?

Comment: Why would you not want it to show the value that it was referencing and just show a meaningless pointer instead?

Comment: Thanks Alex, did you ran it in SQL Developer?

Comment: Hi MT0, I agree. I was just wondering why REF function doesn't return a reference in Oracle SQL Developer, but does it in SQL*Plus.

Comment: @Richard - yes - in version 22.2; it shows the ref if you run as a script; possibly other versions do something different. It looks like the Query Result view does an implicit deref - to be helpful, I guess, as you'd want to see the actual data most of the time.

Comment: @Alex - Thanks. I see. You are right. It is strange that when you run it as statement, it doesn't.